# To store array in $GLOBAL and append values to it from different pages in PHP

Tags: php, global-variables

I need a GLOBAL array to store the history of links I clicked that can be accessed from any php function. When ever I clicked links I need to append that detail in an array.
I used the following code

```
   global $his;
   $dir  = $_REQUEST['dwnpath'];
   array_push($his,$dir);
```

But didn't worked. Any solution for this?

Comment: Didn't work how? Does it receive unemployment benefits? Does it just sit on the couch all day being lazy?

Comment: Your coding in web using HTTP protocol, HTTP it's stateless, meaning variable state it's not saved from one request to the other, but you can save that in sessions.

Answer (score 0):

This method is good when you need the variable in one HTTP request. But if you need it after loading a page which is finished, you may want to use sessions:

```
session_start();

//Create empty array for first push:
$_SESSION['his']=array();

$dir = $_REQUEST['dwnpath'];
array_push($_SESSION['his'],$dir);
```

And now `$_SESSION['his']` is available in all functions.